# Iter not showing every file in directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos

This is my first post in Python. I'm currently teaching myself Python and the current section is iterators.

I'm on a mac running catalina using Python 3.8.3

My goal is to run a directory command for all Python (*.py) files in the current directory. I wrote this code:

```py
import os
files = os.popen('ls *.py')
fileit = iter(files)
for item in files:
    print(next(fileit), end='')
```

It prints a list of every other file and not every python file. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes. Because you are using `next(fileit)` inside your loop, and `files` and `fileit` **are the same iterator**.  See `iter(files) is files`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import glob
for x in glob.glob('*.py', recursive=True):
    print(x)
```

Use `glob` module to retrieve all python files

Modifying your code

```
In [91]: import os
    ...: files = os.popen('ls *.py')
    ...: for item in files:
    ...:     print(item)
```

Output:

```
a.py
main.py
test_main.py
```

Comment: You don’t say what he’s doing wrong, or why your answer is correct. Dumping code on a newbie is not helpful.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar Added description. I think now you can remove your downvote

Comment: I figured out my error...by using "print(next(fileit)) I was advancing my print item. So i was doing what the code was told to do...it just wasn't what I intended to do 

Thanks bigbounty and @asarkar for the quick replies!!!

Comment: @MKS `os.popen('ls *.py')` itself gives an iterator object. So, you can directly run a loop over it

Comment: I will hopefully understand the glob library soon 

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out by walking away and coming back.

The print line should read:

```
print(fileit, end='')
```

by placing it within a next, im advancing the file one place and then printing it, in effect printing every other file name.

Thanks!!

Comment: Shouldn't it be `print(item, end='')`?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use both iterators and a for loop. In this situation a for loop would make the most sense, but if your specifically trying to learn about iterators I would recommend a while loop.

```py
import os
files = os.popen('ls *.py')
fileit = iter(files)
while True:
    try:
        print(next(fileit), end='')
    except StopIteration:
        break
```